# C11 - enums in Generic Selections

Tags: c, generics, enums, selection, c11

```
printf("%i", _Generic(REGISTER_AX, enum SegmentRegister: 0, enum GpRegister: 1, default: 2));
```

In the above code, the desired result is `1`, because `REGISTER_AX` is a member of `enum GpRegister`.
Even though the compiler gladly accepts `enum`s as associated types, the code will print out `2`, because the enum value is evaluated as an `int`.

My question is: Is there a way to produce the desired result, and will an expression in a generic selection ever associate with an `enum` type?

Comment: In C (any release of the standard), enumeration constants are of type int.

Answer (score 6):

Enumeration types are no good test for `_Generic`, and this for two different reasons.

First, as already mentioned in a comment, the constants of such a type are themselves of type `int` and not of the enumeration type.

Second, values that you would declare with that type, say as a variable or with a cast, would be compatible with one specific integer type. Which type that is is implementation (=compiler) dependent and can even vary from one enumeration type to another.

So basically it is not easy to distinguish enumeration types from other integer types. Things become even more difficult if you dig a bit deeper, being compatible types is not a transitive relation.

Comment: Coming from a C++ background, I'm not yet fully versed in the subtleties of C. I'd be interested in knowing the reasoning behind having enumeration constants be of `int` type, as opposed to `enum` type with implicit conversion to int. Also, I do believe that `enum`s are quite incompatible (although implicitly convertible) with both other `enum`s and with `int`. Since the controlling expression is not actually evaluated, there is no implicit conversion to be done, and using several implicitly convertible (but distinct) types in a generic selection should not be a problem at all.

Comment: I don't think that there still is any rationale for all of that. These are historic artefacts, `enum` was introduced in C when all integers basically where still `int`. And C is a conservative language that would need a very good reason to make valid, existing code invalid with a new version of the standard.